# How can I migrate from the dialogflow inline editor to the webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using Dialogflow Inline Editor for some of my agent intents. There are only two files right there (package.json & index.js). If I want to add a response to a new intent, I just write a function with a response string and match this function with an intent name. Pretty simple.

Now, I want to switch from Inline Editor to my own Webhook. I know I have to run something like Express server on my local machine. However, is this a matter of just copying and pasting the content of these two files into my own two files? Or do I need to do something else to make it work.

Moreover, If I do have some complex fulfillment functions within my Inline Editor (interacting with Google Calendar API), how do I pass credentials if I just copy and paste existing code to a local file?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to migrate from serverless function to a server 
Yes, you will have to copy those files and start your own express server

For the server to be webhook, just simply provide a service that can serve POST endpoint for your fulfillment

1. Create your Node.js project
2. Install express, dialogflow-fulfillment lib, and other dependencies
3. Create your POST endpoint for fulfillment
4. Put the link to that endpoint in Dialogflow

> Webhook is just a simple HTTP callback. Dialogflow will trigger the webhook, POST endpoint you provided and after the code execution it will send a response back to the Dialogflow

[image: Webhook Flow]

To attach to Dialogflow webhook you'll just need to provide your webhook endpoint that's serve

By replacing the **URL*** part with your endpoint e.g. https://yourdomain.com/endpointforwebhook

[image: Fullfillment page]

If you develop from your local machine try using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and add a temporary endpoint for the Dialogflow

If for staging or production you'll need a real domain for endpoint
simply start from deploying your express server to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and add an endpoint for the Dialogflow

**For the credentials part in your local files**
You can manage your credentials in the local file with environment env or some configuration management. See [Dotenv npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)